# Org timestamps with timezones?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** (how) can I get `org` timestamps to include time zones?

I'm working with colleagues who live in different time zones.
When we set up phone calls and appointments, we often do the
elaborate and error-prone "X o'clock your time, X-Y o'clock mine"
dance.

I'd like to be able to schedule (or set a deadline for) a call
with an explicit time zone (e.g., "X o'clock **EST**"), and then
let `org` mode worry about doing the mental math for me based on
the time zone I happen to be in at the time.

*Can I get timezone-aware timestamps in `org-mode`, and how?*

Comment: As of yet, as can also be seen in the other question, the answer is no.